# Code coverage when not testing protected/private methods with PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, code-coverage

I know it's possible to test private/protected methods with PHPUnit using reflection or other workarounds.

But most sources tell me that it's **not** best practice to write tests for private methods inside of a class.

You are supposed to test the class as if it were a "black box" — you just test for expected behavior by comparing inputs with outputs disregarding the internal mechanics. Writing tests for classes should also notify you to unused private methods, by showing lack of code coverage.

When I test my class and generate an HTML report, it shows the private methods as not covered by tests, even though the lines from which they are called are absolutely executed/covered. I know that the private methods are executed, because if they weren't the assertions on my class would not pass.

Is this expected behavior in PHPUnit? Can I strive for 100% coverage, while still testing private methods only indirectly?

Some simplified example code (using RestBundle in Symfony2):

```
class ApiController extends FOSRestController {

/*
 * @REST\View()
 * @REST\Get("/api/{codes}")
 */
public function getCodesAction($codes) {
    $view = new View();
    $view->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $view->setData(array('type' => 'codes','data' => $this->_stringToArray($codes)));
    $view->setFormat('json')->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $this->handleView($view);
}

private function _stringToArray($string){
    return explode('+',$string);
}
```

The public function shows as "covered", the private function is indirectly covered but shows colored red in PHPUnit reports.

Test:

```
class ApiControllerTest extends WebTestCase {

    public function test_getCodesAction(){
        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->request('GET', '/api/1+2+3');
        $this->assertContains('{"type": "codes", "data": [1,2,3]}', $client->getResponse()->getContent());
    }

}
```

This is just a silly example of course, I could just as well include the explode() right there in the public function; But the controllers I'm writing tests for contain much more intricate and re-usable private functions which transform data in more complex ways (but are still side-effect free).

Comment: Testing private methods isn't a problem by itself - doing such tests is not a bad practice. It's having private methods in the first place that's considered harmful, because they're hard to test.

Comment: @narf, I'd disagree with that. testing private methods makes for brittle tests and I would consider it a bad code smell if you think your only option is to resort to testing by reflection. Private methods are not harmful, they are a good way of organizing the code inside a class.

Comment: @SamHolder Brittle is better than nothing ... there's no logic in *having* a test to be a bad practice and you can't convince me in that. :) Anyway, what, how and to what extent to test is largely an opinion-based topic, so I'd rather agree to disagree with you. :)

Comment: @narf you should test based on publicly verifiable behaviour. Private methods are an implementation detail.

Comment: @SamHolder If that behavior depends on private methods, they're not just an implementation detail. Honestly, I'm very far from these people who'd scream at you for not testing your code, but nothing that you say could possibly convince me. I won't write more replies in order to avoid a flame war.

Comment: @narf shame that you are closed minded on the subject. You seem to be taking my position as 'don't test the code in private methods' when actually it is 'test all the code through public methods. if you happen to have put some of that code in private methods called by the public methods, that is fine. irrelevant, but fine'. Please see my answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568288/how-to-refactor-tests-in-tdd/30568389#30568389) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381174/confused-on-how-to-write-tests-for-classes-that-are-refactored-to-compose-other/27382872#27382872)

Comment: @narf or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103346/dealing-with-duplication-between-unit-and-integration-tests/27103592#27103592)

Comment: Private functions often get compared to "thoughts" as opposed to the "talking" public functions. People who talk more than they think tend to be annoying, and the same goes for the balance between public helper functions in their own services and private functions inside of their controllers/services in my opinion. Privates are quite useful to distill side-effect-free repetitive code into something which is reusable for *that specific class*, but which isn't useful anywhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Phpunit you can specify the Covered Methods with special annotation, as descrived in the [doc](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html#code-coverage-analysis.specifying-covered-methods).

You can do something like this:

```
    class ApiControllerTest extends WebTestCase {

        /**
         * @covers ApiController::getCodesAction
         * @covers ApiController::_stringToArray
         */
        public function test_getCodesAction(){
            $client = static::createClient();
            $client->request('GET', '/api/1+2+3');
            $this->assertContains('{"type": "codes", "data": [1,2,3]}', $client->getResponse()->getContent());
        }

    }
```

Hope this help

Comment: Cool! I did not realize that I could place multiple @covers annotations on one test function. I thought they had to match the public functions! I checked it, and also discovered that an if branch in a private function was completely redundant, so it's already paying off!

Comment: Hi @SamHolder of course, the question is about the code coverage, so i respond how to ignore/trick the code coverage. Yes, the method in the detail can be wrapped in a simple util class that should be unit tested in an isolated scope itself.

Comment: Hi @Matteo. I wasn't commenting on the quality of your answer, which may well be perfect, more on the fact that if this *is* the solution the G*d help all PHP developers.

Comment: @SamHolder, excuse me, I'm new to unit testing. I'd welcome any advice, but the PHPUnit docs specifically use covers annotations for coverage reporting. Or is there a better way in your opinion? Also, yeah, I'd gladly ditch PHP/Symfony in favor of something functional like Haskell/Snap, but in the real world you work in larger teams with armies of cheap junior devs, and 90% of web development is dirty coding in abused PHP frameworks without any form of planning or documentation. And it pays well.

Comment: But I'd love to see the "proper" answer, as you've also made comments in favor of using private methods inside of classes ;)

Comment: @Feroxium I'm not a PHP developer, just an advocate of unit testing, and if this is the best that PHP can offer then my advice would be to learn c#, java, python, ruby or something that's not PHP. Isuspect that all of those pay as well as PHP, and functional languages pay even better.